# Scatter Plot graphing excel VBA - wont graph my range of data

Tags: vba, excel, graph

Here's the section of the code that is giving me trouble. I incorporated messagebox's to let me know that things are working up to that given point. So when I type "MsgBox xaxis.Address()" it comes out like $C$20:$C$42. Which is what im looking to graph on the x-axis. The issue is, my graph doesnt actually show up with that on the x-axis... it graphs like the entire sheet. I am guessing my issue lies with the syntax of xaxis that I am using.

```
    Dim StartTime As Range
    Dim EndTime As Range


    Set StartTime = wb1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C").Find(wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$B$2").Text, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set EndTime = wb1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C").Find(wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Text, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)
    'If Not StartTime Is Nothing Then
    'End If


     MsgBox StartTime.Address()
     MsgBox EndTime.Address()
     MsgBox StartTime.Value
     MsgBox EndTime.Value
     MsgBox "Hi"

     Dim xaxis As Range
     Dim yaxis As Range
     Set xaxis = Range(StartTime.Address & ":" & EndTime.Address)
     MsgBox xaxis.Address
    'Set xaxis = Range("$C$16", Range("$C$16").End(xlDown))
     Set yaxis = xaxis.Offset(0, ColumnOffset:=1)

     MsgBox yaxis.Address

     '''''''''''''''''''''''

     'Dim x As String
     'Dim y As String

     ' x = xaxis.Address
     'MsgBox "Hi"
     'y = yaxis.Address
     'MsgBox x

     Set Chrt = Charts.Add
     With Chrt
         .ChartType = xlXYScatter
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                '.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Scatter Chart"""
                .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yaxis
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xaxis


                'Titles
                .HasTitle = True
                .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Platen1"
                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Seconds)"
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temp (Deg. C)"
                .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

                'Formatting
                .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
                .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
                .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
                .HasLegend = False
            End With
```

My overall goal: I have a spreadsheet with data that gets updated daily. I need the user to be able to input a start time, end time, and then machine number. This needs to be used to generate a graph from that data. The start and end time are always in column C, but the specific rows are always changing. So what I do is I locate the matching start time and end time from the data, and then I create this range (StartTime or EndTime). The machine will determine the column of data to use for the y-axis which im just offsetting from the x-axis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I fixed the above by adding the following code right under the chart creation:

```
      Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
      .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
      Loop
```

The issue i realize is that the "xaxis" and "yaxis" are grabbing data from Sheet1 while i want it to grab data from Sheet 2. How do I go about declaring that it should be graphing from Sheet2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
 Set xaxis = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(StartTime.Address & ":" & EndTime.Address)
 Set yaxis = xaxis.Offset(0, ColumnOffset:=1)
```

Comment: Wow! thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't think of that haha